Subtracting Values Based on Group Conditions in R
I have a data frame that includes id and value columns (example below).
df <- data.frame(
  id = c("var1", "var1", "var1", "var2", "var2", "var2", "var3", "var3", "var3"),
  var = c(1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11),
  value = c(2024, 2023, 2022, 2023, 2022, 2021, 2024, 2023, 2022)
)

I want to subtract 1 from each value within a group if the maximum value in that group is 2024.
Expected output:
    id var value
1 var1   1  2023
2 var1   2  2022
3 var1   3  2021
4 var2   4  2023
5 var2   6  2022
6 var2   7  2021
7 var3   9  2023
8 var3  10  2022
9 var3  11  2021


Please add an example of what you've tried so far and how it failed to give the expected outcome.

The logical condition will be coerced to 1 if TRUE and 0 if FALSE when used in arithmetic.
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(value = value - (max(value) == 2024), .by = id)

giving
    id var value
1 var1   1  2023
2 var1   2  2022
3 var1   3  2021
4 var2   4  2023
5 var2   6  2022
6 var2   7  2021
7 var3   9  2023
8 var3  10  2022
9 var3  11  2021

